# Taking control of WSDL/XSD from WCF-SVCUtil (Annotations, Schema Namespaces, and Schema Locations)

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl

In the WSDL that is generated from a WCF service, there are a few problems that I'd like to take control of a little more. First, is there a way to add annotations to the xsd files generated with the WSDL without using surrogates?

  I've taken care of adding annotations to the WSDL itself thanks to the following articles:
  - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx)

    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29980/Exporting-Annotations-from-WCF
  I was able to add annotations to data members through agillior, however they used surrogates which I would rather not use.
  - http://agilior.pt/blogs/bruno.camara/archive/2006/10/01/6.aspx
  I would use Thoranin's solution except I want to apply the annotations to data members not parameters
  - http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/08/08/Controlling-WSDL-minOccurs-with-WCF.aspx

---

<strike>Second, I want to explicitly name the namespaces for the xsd files generated from the WSDL. I was able to take control over the namespace of the wsdl using the ServiceBehaviorAttribute:     `[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://mysite.com/HelloWorld")]`

but unfortunately I can't find an easy way to specify the namespace of the xsd files :(, is there a simple way to do this/can you point me in the right direction?</strike>

-edit-
Well I was being silly on the second request. I had forgotten to set the namespaces for my wcf files which is what maps to the xsd namespaces. My bad :) .

---

Lastly, when the wsdl imports an xsd, it uses a path similar to     `http://localhost:8080/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc?xsd=xsd0`

which seems to break the wsdl2java ant script by apache. I can go in and manually change them to the local files but it's just such a pain :). Is there any way to have the files generated and then have a local reference like:
`HelloWorldService.xsd`,`HelloWorldService1.xsd` etc?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCFExtras ftw:

I decided that instead of having my own attributes and classes put documentation/annotation into the WSDL and XSD files I would just give into the hype and let WCFExtras take care of it. That being said I do wish that the Xml comments would be split into different lines instead of having them all on the same line. (Just to make reading the xml files easier). Plus WCFExtras takes care of the surrogate problem perfectly :) !

Ended up writing a program to solve the third issue. It pretty much grabs the metadata files using svcutil then goes in and finds all the imports, and reassigns them to the files downloaded based of off the namespaces.